# How can I convert a date to epoch time?

Tags: perl

I have a huge formatted file of the form:

```
29/01/2010 18:00 string1 string2 .....

30/01/2010 18:30 string3 string4 .....

...

...

dd/mm/yyyy hh:MM strings strings....
```

I need to perform some statistics based on the dates.

So I would like to substitute the string `dd/mm/yyyy hh:MM` with epoch time in the file in order to perform simple manipulations.

I suppose that the best way is to use Perl, but I really don't know where to start. Any hints?

Comment: even we dont know where to start.Any Hints?... you havent mentioned whose epoch time.. unix, windows...which?.. also.. what are you trying to do in statics..how come you decided pearl is best for this..

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Just that? This quick-and-dirty one-liner should do:

```
perl -MPOSIX -pwe 's{^(\d{2})/(\d{2})/(\d{4}) (\d{2}):(\d{2}) }{mktime(0,$5,$4,$1,$2-1,$3-1900)." "}e;'
```

Feed it the file on standard input and it will output the changed version to standard output. All it does is look for lines that have "dd/mm/yyyy hh:mm " at the start, and feed the date components to the `mktime` function from the `POSIX` module to get a unix timestamp.

Comment: How do you use this inside a script though?

Answer (score 2):

```
use DateTime::Format::Strptime;

my $Strp = new DateTime::Format::Strptime(
        pattern     => '%d/%m/%Y %H:%M',
        locale      => 'en_EN',
        time_zone   => 'UTC',
);

open INPUT, $file;
while (<INPUT>)
{
   my ($date, $time, $foo) = split(' ', $_, 3);
   my $dt = $Strp->parse_datetime("$date $time");
   printf "%s %s", $dt->strftime('%s'), $foo;
}
close INPUT;
```

Comment: LOL. Anomie's response is quicker-and-dirtier than mine's. I love it. Recommended!

Comment: Your response could be quicker and dirtier too with a simple `s/^(\S+ \S+)/$Strp->parse_datetime($1)->epoch/e`.

Comment: Thanks for the tip Christoffer. I never get accustomed to code using fewer lines and saving auxiliar variables.

Answer (score 1):

You could use the core module [Time::Local](http://perldoc.perl.org/Time/Local.html)

```
#!/usr/bin/perl
use 5.10.1;
use strict;
use warnings;
use Time::Local;


while(<DATA>) {
    if (m#(\d+)/(\d+)/(\d+)\s+(\d+):(\d+)\s#) {
        say timelocal(0,$5,$4,$1,$2-1,$3);
    }
}

__DATA__
29/01/2010 18:00 string1 string2 .....

30/01/2010 18:30 string3 string4 .....
```

**output:**

```
1264784400
1264872600
```